# Is Google Play app signing mandatory post Aug 2021?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, google-play-developer-api, android-app-signing

Is opting in for Google Play app signing mandatory post Aug 2021?

Is there a way to create new app in google play console without accepting play app signing terms in declaration form or without opting in for play app signing ??

Looks like bundles are the only way to upload Apps to Google Play now and using Bundles makes it mandatory to have the private key with Google.

Is my assumption correct, that Developers are now forced to share the private key for signing with Google?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google is trying to force everyone to use the AAB format,but in my experience if the console shows drop an aab file here, and you drop an apk, i'll process that too
Not sure how long google will keep this as from UI perspective there is no mention of apk file in play console at this stage
Maybe google will stop accepting apk at all in coming months or 2022

You can always upload your custom keystore as signing key though

Also, for existing apps, Google doesn't force you to move to aab

Comment: Thank you @omkar T for the quick response. The problem is we can't upload our app signing key for now. Is there a way to go ahead without opting in to play app signing ?

Comment: You can let google generate a new key for you in that case, but you will not be able to download it and sign your apk in case you want to distribute your apk outside play store with same signature (Play protect will flag your app as untrusted and prompt user to uninstall it if it sees the signature not matching with its own registered one even though same dev has used different key)